# What is difference between this two time formats and how to convert

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I have a date like this from database: `"2019-12-06T00:00:00.000Z"`.
But I need it like `"2019-12-06T00:00:00Z"`.

I tried to convert first one to date and to ISO string but I don't get what I need.

```
let s = "2019-12-06T00:00:00.000Z";
let dt = new Date(s).toISOString();
```

This print same.

Comment: how do you want the date to be?

Comment: "2019-12-06T00:00:00Z"

Comment: You want to remove the milliseconds…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number `00:00:00.000` are `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds` and `miliseconds` respectively. So to remove miliseconds

Try this:

```js
  let s = "2019-12-06T00:00:00.000Z";
  let dt = new Date(s).toISOString().split('.')[0]+"Z" ;
  console.log(dt);
```

Comment: Yes it does. I miss another answer while searching. It is duplicate. Thanks

Comment: Why down vote?? Please let me know the mistake I will fix it :)

Comment: This is the exact answer as the duplicate.

Comment: @adiga two person can't have same thinking? Btw I checked that and I am removing this :)

Comment: OP can't delete question with answers. There is no point in keeping it. (And I din't downvote)

Comment: @1110 let me know if you want to delete it. I will remove my answer :)